# How do I define the TBBUTTON struct in C#?

Tags: c#, interop, 64-bit

Greetings all,

The TBBUTTON struct is defined on MSDN as follows:

```
typedef struct {
  int       iBitmap;
  int       idCommand;
  BYTE      fsState;
  BYTE      fsStyle;
#ifdef _WIN64
  BYTE      bReserved[6];
#else 
#if defined(_WIN32)
  BYTE      bReserved[2];
#endif 
#endif 
  DWORD_PTR dwData;
  INT_PTR   iString;
} TBBUTTON, *PTBBUTTON, *LPTBBUTTON;
```

I need to do some interop in C# using this struct.  How do I replicate this monster so that it's defined correctly when compiled for AnyCPU?  Google is apparently full of dangerous misinformation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahah, I knew there had to be a way.  And here it is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TBBUTTON {
    public int iBitmap;
    public int idCommand;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private struct TBBUTTON_U {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public byte fsState;
        [FieldOffset(1)] public byte fsStyle;
        [FieldOffset(0)] private IntPtr bReserved;
    }
    private TBBUTTON_U union;
    public byte fsState { get { return union.fsState; } set { union.fsState = value; } }
    public byte fsStyle { get { return union.fsStyle; } set { union.fsStyle = value; } }
    public UIntPtr dwData;
    public IntPtr iString;
}
```

`Marshal.SizeOf` returns 32 on x64 processes and 20 on x86 processes, and everything ends up where it should when I pass this to `SendMessage`.  I knew you could do it, C#!

Comment: That's it. Thank you for not paying attention to comments like "it's the only way".

Comment: Indeed, it works! Can someone give some insight into why it works, though?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to define two versions, one for 32 bit and one for 64 bit.

```
public struct TBBUTTON32
{
    int       iBitmap;
    int       idCommand;
    byte      fsState;
    byte      fsStyle;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    byte[]    bReserved;
    UIntPtr   dwData;
    IntPtr    iString;
}
```

The 64 bit version is just the same but with `SizeConst = 6` on the reserved bytes array.

Then you need to switch between them at runtime. Your C# code will have to detect whether it's running as a 32 or 64 bit process.

Comment: Ugh... Is there no way to avoid this?  Surely there must be a way to do it at compile time...

Comment: if you use AnyCPU then you inevitably delay the decision to runtime

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: If it's the only way, it's the only way...  I'm disappointed in you, C#!

Comment: Attribute arguments must be constant expressions. I expect you could write your own custom marshaller but that would be even more yucky!