# TBBUTTON struct not working with SendMessage

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, marshalling, readprocessmemory

I'm trying to send the **[TB_GETBUTTON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787319%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** message to get info about the buttons inside this Toolbar control marked in red color:

[image]

( The System tray notification area )

The problem is that when I send the message, the *Explorer* refreshes itself, is very annonying because all the desktop refreshes, and also I'm not getting the proper values with the **[TBBUTTON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** structure definition that I'm using, I tested three different definitions, those with unions from **[pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/TBBUTTON.html)**, and the one published **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5496051/1248295)** by @**David Heffernan**.

I'm running the code below in a 64-Bit Windows 10 and with the x64 config set in my project properties.

How can I fix the struct and the annonying system's refresh?.

These are the relevant definitions I'm using:

```
Const WM_USER As Integer = &H400
Const TB_BUTTONCOUNT As Integer = (WM_USER + 24)
Const TB_GETBUTTON As Integer = (WM_USER + 23)
' Toolbar values are defined in "CommCtrl.h" Windows SDK header files.

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure TBBUTTON64
    Public iBitmap As Integer
    Public idCommand As Integer
    Public fsState As Byte
    Public fsStyle As Byte
    <MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=6)> ' 6 on x64
    Public bReserved As Byte()
    Public dwData As UIntPtr
    Public iString As IntPtr
End Structure

<DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Public Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr,
                                   ByVal msg As Integer,
                                   ByVal wParam As IntPtr,
                                   ByVal lParam As IntPtr
) As IntPtr
End Function

<SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
<DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, BestFitMapping:=False, ThrowOnUnmappableChar:=True)>
Public Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String,
                                  ByVal lpWindowName As String
) As IntPtr
End Function

<SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
<DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, BestFitMapping:=False, ThrowOnUnmappableChar:=True)>
Public Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal hwndParent As IntPtr,
                                    ByVal hwndChildAfter As IntPtr,
                                    ByVal strClassName As String,
                                    ByVal strWindowName As String
) As IntPtr
End Function
```

And this is the code to test them:

```
Dim tskBarHwnd As IntPtr =
    NativeMethods.FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", Nothing)

Dim systrayBarHwnd As IntPtr =
    NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(tskBarHwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "TrayNotifyWnd", Nothing)

Dim sysPagerHwnd As IntPtr =
    NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(systrayBarHwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "SysPager", Nothing)

Dim ntfyBarHwnd As IntPtr =
    NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(sysPagerHwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "ToolbarWindow32", Nothing)

Dim buttonCount As Integer =
    NativeMethods.SendMessage(ntfyBarHwnd, TB_BUTTONCOUNT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero).ToInt32()

For index As Integer = 0 To (buttonCount - 1)

    Dim btInfo As New TBBUTTON64
    Dim alloc As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(TBBUTTON64)))

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(btInfo, alloc, fDeleteOld:=True)
    NativeMethods.SendMessage(ntfyBarHwnd, TB_GETBUTTON, New IntPtr(index), alloc)
    Marshal.PtrToStructure(Of TBBUTTON64)(alloc)
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(alloc)

    ' This line always prints "00000"
    Console.WriteLine(btInfo.iBitmap &
                      btInfo.fsState &
                      btInfo.fsStyle &
                      btInfo.idCommand &
                      btInfo.iString.ToInt32())
Next index
```

---

### UPDATE (25-MARCH-2019)

I came back on this need because now I need to hide a sys-tray icon of a external app. So I started investigating again these days...

Please note the commentary did by @**Remy Lebeau**:

> TB_GETBUTTON can be sent to another process. You just have to give it
>   the address of a TBBUTTON that exists in the target process's address
>   space. Use VirtualAllocEx() to allocate it, then send the message,
>   then use ReadProcessMemory() to read its content.

I'm not sure at all how to reproduce the steps that he gave, but after investigating a lot I found a code that apparently does that, it seem to read the process memory to retrieve the icon text:

- [Get ToolTip Text from Icon in System Tray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392066/1248295)

However, it is written in C#, using `unsafe` and `fixed` keywords and I'm not sure how to translate it entirely in a proper way. Also, and just as a personal opinion, I feel that code is not simplified in any way, and I see bad design practices with var nomenclatures like "b", "b2" and "b4" which I don't get their purpose at all...

And, if helpful, I also found this in C/C++:

- [Shell Tray Info - Arrange your system tray icons](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10807/Shell-Tray-Info-Arrange-your-system-tray-icons)

In resume, what I'm asking for is to reproduce in VB.NET code the solution pointed by @**Remy Lebeau**, or to translate and simplify the C# code that I mentioned.

This is the best I can do by the moment with the help of a code converter, note that this code **IS NOT** working (it is broken / not fully converted to VB.NET):

```
Private Function GetTBButton(ByVal hToolbar As IntPtr, ByVal i As Integer, ByRef tbButton As ToolBarButton64, ByRef text As String, ByRef ipWindowHandle As IntPtr) As Boolean

    ' One page
    Const BUFFER_SIZE As Integer = &H1000

    Dim localBuffer(BUFFER_SIZE - 1) As Byte

    Dim processId As Integer = 0
    Dim threadId As Integer = NativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hToolbar, processId)

    Dim hProcess As IntPtr = NativeMethods.OpenProcess(ProcessAccessRights.AllAccess, False, processId)
    If hProcess = IntPtr.Zero Then
        Debug.Assert(False)
        Return False
    End If

    Dim ipRemoteBuffer As UIntPtr = NativeMethods.VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, New UIntPtr(BUFFER_SIZE), MemoryAllocationType.Commit, MemoryProtectionOptions.ReadWrite)

    If ipRemoteBuffer = UIntPtr.Zero Then
        Debug.Assert(False)
        Return False
    End If

    ' TBButton
    'INSTANT VB TODO TASK: There is no equivalent to a 'fixed' block in VB:
    '       fixed (TBBUTTON* pTBButton = &tbButton)
    Dim ipTBButton As New IntPtr(pTBButton)

    Dim b As Integer = CInt(Math.Truncate(NativeMethods.SendMessage(hToolbar, TB.GETBUTTON, CType(i, IntPtr), ipRemoteBuffer)))
    If b = 0 Then
        Debug.Assert(False)
        Return False
    End If

    ' this is fixed
    Dim dwBytesRead As Int32 = 0
    Dim ipBytesRead As New IntPtr(& dwBytesRead)

    'INSTANT VB TODO TASK: There is no VB equivalent to 'sizeof':
    Dim b2 As Boolean = NativeMethods.ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, ipRemoteBuffer, ipTBButton, New UIntPtr(CUInt(Math.Truncate(Marshal.SizeOf(tbButton)))), ipBytesRead)

    If Not b2 Then
        Debug.Assert(False)
        Return False
    End If
    'INSTANT VB NOTE: End of the original C# 'fixed' block.

    ' button text
    'INSTANT VB TODO TASK: There is no equivalent to a 'fixed' block in VB:
    '       fixed (byte* pLocalBuffer = localBuffer)
    Dim ipLocalBuffer As New IntPtr(pLocalBuffer)

    Dim chars As Integer = CInt(Math.Truncate(NativeMethods.SendMessage(hToolbar, TB.GETBUTTONTEXTW, CType(tbButton.idCommand, IntPtr), ipRemoteBuffer)))
    If chars = -1 Then
        Debug.Assert(False)
        Return False
    End If

    ' this is fixed
    Dim dwBytesRead As Integer = 0
    Dim ipBytesRead As New IntPtr(& dwBytesRead)

    Dim b4 As Boolean = NativeMethods.ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, ipRemoteBuffer, ipLocalBuffer, New UIntPtr(BUFFER_SIZE), ipBytesRead)

    If Not b4 Then
        Debug.Assert(False)
        Return False
    End If

    text = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ipLocalBuffer, chars)

    If text = " " Then
        text = String.Empty
    End If
    'INSTANT VB NOTE: End of the original C# 'fixed' block.

    NativeMethods.VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, ipRemoteBuffer, UIntPtr.Zero, MemoryFreeType.Release)
    NativeMethods.CloseHandle(hProcess)

    Return True

End Function
```

Which in theory it would be called like this:

```
Dim sysTrayHwnd As IntPtr = NotificationAreaUtil.Hwnd
Dim btIndex As Integer = 0
Dim tbButton As New ToolBarButton64() ' TBBUTTON struct for a x64 process
Dim text As String
Dim ipHwnd As IntPtr

GetTBButton(sysTrayHwnd, btIndex , tbButton, text, ipHwnd)
```

---

### UPDATE (13-APRIL-2019)

I tried to convert the C/C++ solution provided by @RbMm in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55631705/1248295) answer, however, I'm getting a related memory error through a **System.AccessViolationException** when I try to marshal the TBBUTTON structure at this line:

```
...
Dim ptbi As ToolBarButtonInfo = Marshal.PtrToStructure(Of ToolBarButtonInfo)(remoteBaseAddress)
...
```

Note that to ensure that the root of the problem was not a bad TBBUTTONINFOW definition from my side, instead of using `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` I just used the `Marshal.ReadInt32()` function to try read a single field on the specific offset, and I get the same kind of error.

Probably I'm doing something wrong because I don't manage C/C++. Here is my attempt of code conversion in VB.NET:

( I will omit to share the P/Invoke definitions to simplify the code example )

```
Dim sysTray As IntPtr = NotificationAreaUtil.Hwnd
Dim pid As Integer
If (NativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(sysTray, pid) <> 0) Then
    Dim hProcess As IntPtr = NativeMethods.OpenProcess(ProcessAccessRights.VirtualMemoryOperation, False, pid)
    If (hProcess <> IntPtr.Zero) Then

        Dim hSection As IntPtr
        Dim pageSize As ULong = 81920 ' LARGE_INTEGER
        Dim viewSize As IntPtr ' SIZE_T
        Dim baseAddress As IntPtr ' PVOID
        Dim remoteBaseAddress As IntPtr ' PVOID

        If (NativeMethods.NtCreateSection(hSection, SectionAccessRights.AllAccess,
                                          IntPtr.Zero, pageSize,
                                          MemoryProtectionOptions.ReadWrite,
                                          SectionAttributes.Commit,
                                          IntPtr.Zero) = NTStatus.SUCCESS) Then

            If (NativeMethods.NtMapViewOfSection(hSection, NativeMethods.GetCurrentProcess(), baseAddress,
                                                 IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, viewSize,
                                                 ViewOfSectionInherit.ViewUnmap,
                                                 MemoryAllocationType.Default,
                                                 MemoryProtectionOptions.ReadWrite) = NTStatus.SUCCESS) Then


                If (NativeMethods.NtMapViewOfSection(hSection, hProcess, remoteBaseAddress,
                                                     IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, viewSize,
                                                     ViewOfSectionInherit.ViewUnmap,
                                                     MemoryAllocationType.Default,
                                                     MemoryProtectionOptions.ReadWrite) = NTStatus.SUCCESS) Then

                    Dim btIndex As Integer = 3 ' Button index from which I'll try to retrieve a valid TBBUTTONINFOW struct.
                    ' Const TBIF_BYINDEX As Integer = &H80000000
                    ' Const TBIF_TEXT As Integer = &H2 

                    If (NativeMethods.SendMessage(sysTray, ToolbarMessages.GetButtonInfoUnicode, New IntPtr(btIndex), remoteBaseAddress) <> IntPtr.Zero) Then

                        ' AT THIS LINE THROWS THE ACCESSVIOLATIONEXCEPTION.
                        Dim ptbi As ToolBarButtonInfo = Marshal.PtrToStructure(Of ToolBarButtonInfo)(remoteBaseAddress)

                        Console.WriteLine(ptbi.CommandId)
                        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptbi.Text))

                    Else
                        Throw New Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())

                    End If

                    NativeMethods.NtUnmapViewOfSection(hProcess, remoteBaseAddress)
                End If

                NativeMethods.NtUnmapViewOfSection(NativeMethods.GetCurrentProcess(), baseAddress)
            End If

            NativeMethods.NtClose(hSection)
        End If

        NativeMethods.CloseHandle(hProcess)
    End If

End If
```

And here is a code conversion(on-the-fly and not tested) to C# of the code above:

```
IntPtr sysTray = NotificationAreaUtil.Hwnd;
int pid = 0;
if (NativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(sysTray, pid) != 0)
{
    IntPtr hProcess = NativeMethods.OpenProcess(ProcessAccessRights.VirtualMemoryOperation, false, pid);
    if (hProcess != IntPtr.Zero)
    {

        IntPtr hSection = System.IntPtr.Zero;
        ulong pageSize = 81920; // LARGE_INTEGER
        IntPtr viewSize = System.IntPtr.Zero; // SIZE_T
        IntPtr baseAddress = System.IntPtr.Zero; // PVOID
        IntPtr remoteBaseAddress = System.IntPtr.Zero; // PVOID

        if (NativeMethods.NtCreateSection(hSection, SectionAccessRights.AllAccess, IntPtr.Zero, pageSize, MemoryProtectionOptions.ReadWrite, SectionAttributes.Commit, IntPtr.Zero) == NTStatus.SUCCESS)
        {

            if (NativeMethods.NtMapViewOfSection(hSection, NativeMethods.GetCurrentProcess(), baseAddress, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, viewSize, ViewOfSectionInherit.ViewUnmap, MemoryAllocationType.Default, MemoryProtectionOptions.ReadWrite) == NTStatus.SUCCESS)
            {


                if (NativeMethods.NtMapViewOfSection(hSection, hProcess, remoteBaseAddress, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, viewSize, ViewOfSectionInherit.ViewUnmap, MemoryAllocationType.Default, MemoryProtectionOptions.ReadWrite) == NTStatus.SUCCESS)
                {

                    int btIndex = 3; // Button index from which I'll try to retrieve a valid TBBUTTONINFOW struct.

                    if (NativeMethods.SendMessage(sysTray, ToolbarMessages.GetButtonInfoUnicode, new IntPtr(btIndex), remoteBaseAddress) != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {

                        // AT THIS LINE THROWS THE ACCESSVIOLATIONEXCEPTION.
                        ToolBarButtonInfo ptbi = Marshal.PtrToStructure<ToolBarButtonInfo>(remoteBaseAddress);

                        Console.WriteLine(ptbi.CommandId);
                        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptbi.Text));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                    }

                    NativeMethods.NtUnmapViewOfSection(hProcess, remoteBaseAddress);
                }

                NativeMethods.NtUnmapViewOfSection(NativeMethods.GetCurrentProcess(), baseAddress);
            }

            NativeMethods.NtClose(hSection);
        }

        NativeMethods.CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#UIAutomationClientsideProviders/MS/Internal/AutomationProxies/CommonXSendMessage.cs,d6764b5a08c7e1e8,references

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå Thankyou so much for finding that, however I translated Microsoft's TBBUTTON_64 and TBBUTTON structs to VB.NET (with Telerik's online convert tool, any manual change needed in the translation) but I'm getting exactlly the same problems described in my question, a system refresh and any values returned in the struct.

Comment: Why would these messages be marshaled? The window lives in a different process. Why are you hacking in this way. Can't it be done a supported way.

Comment: @David Heffernan Thanks for comment, my real purpose is to find a way to be able identify those buttons of the notification area, then hide a specific button that matches "X" name, for that I expect that the iString member of the TBBUTTON structure will give me the info I need, the button name, that is the reason for why I'm trying to use that struct, however is just speculation because I cannot test the struct for the problems I described in my question. Maybe you know any managed or unmanaged alternative for what I really want to do?

Comment: You aren't supposed to automate this. It belongs to the user. Stop it.

Comment: @David Heffernan If with those words you meaning about ethic reasons, I will clarify that I'm trying to automate this for my only personal usage on my machine, there is an icon that disturbs me but I need to keep running the process that owns that notifyicon then I tried to find a way to hide it programatically (without directlly doing reverse engineering on the executable to avoid the icon showing), also doing this helps me to learn a little bit more about some Win32 aspects. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You aren't allowed to do that. Such software is malware. But anyway, you didn't address my very first question.

Comment: Which program's icon?

Comment: @David Heffernan I thought that you're very first question was rhetorical, I don't have an answer for why happens that (that is why I'm asking for help, I think), however I could say you that the **TB_BUTTONCOUNT** message works perfect with that control, then why the **TB_GETBUTTON** shouldn't work?.

Comment: Think about it. The record is in your address space. You pass its address. How is the other process going to read it. Is it marshaled or not? If you really want to learn why not learn something practical?

Comment: @andlabs Is not any icon of a commercial app, anyways I'm not going to do spam of the name, that would result in more critics about me and I don't know why I should be giving explanations for external ethical things that has nothing to do with the programming question I did. Thanks for comment.

Comment: I was going to suggest asking the developer of that program to simply add a feature to disable the notification icon. The thing with ethics and programming is that Microsoft built the system so that [the only things that are programmatically possible are the things that are ethically desirable](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030903-00/?p=42673). Legitimate cases where the otherwise-undesirable action is necessary get caught in the crossfire, unfortunately.

Comment: The feature you are trying to replicate is built into the Shell already. Simply uninstall your Shell replacement.

Comment: @ElektroStudios why not just go into the Taskbar settings and hide the desired icon? No code needed. No contacting the author needed. Hiding notification icons has been a standard features of Windows for several versions now.

Comment: "my real purpose is to find a way to be able identify those buttons of the notification area, then hide a specific button that matches "X" name... I need, the button name" --  As your ultimate goal is to retrieve the button name, are you adamant about using your proposed method or open to other means of obtaining the name?  Are you familiar with the [Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinAuto/inspect-objects) program?  I would suggest you try using that program to determine if the name reported to UIAutomation would work for your needs.

Comment: @TnTinMn I can access the toolbar button through its accessibility name via UI Automation, but I think I can't do anything useful with it like hide or destroy it. The obtained automation element does not provide a window handle, and **Inspect** says it only provides the **Invoke** and **LegacyIAccessible** patterns.

Comment: TnTinMn At this point I only would like to learn how to do (in VB.NET) what @Remy Lebeau suggested, the reason is time ago I had implemented and documented all the win32 toolbar control messages, all their related structures (**TBBUTTON**, **TBBUTTONINFO**, **TBMETRICS**, etc), enums, and the required native functions, so now I have a bunch of P/Invokes and members in general that took me time and effort to write and document, but are totally useless code unless I can send **TB_GETBUTTON** or **TB_GETBUTTONINFO** toolbar message to the Windows system-tray in the right way. Thanks for comment.

Comment: Also please note that my ultimate goal is not to retrieve the button name. The first step is to identify the button by its (known) name, that is just to retrieve its button index, and finally send **TB_DELETEBUTTON** toolbar message to delete that button passing its button index.

Comment: I thought you had a means of accessing the button once you had the name. After a quick review, it appears that you are going down the correct path. I don't have enough interest in this to post a .Net solution, but I found a [CP article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10807/Shell-Tray-Info-Arrange-your-system-tray-icons) in C++ that manipulates the buttons. That article uses [another article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/10642/cprocessdata-a-template-class-to-ease-up-sendmessa) that is for a helper class to access the memory and shows the VirtualAllocEx/ReadProcessMemory method.

Comment: @ElektroStudios *"without directlly doing reverse engineering on the executable to avoid the icon showing"*, really? Reverse engineer for hiding an icon? Why don't you just open taskbar notification settings and hide it?  https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000734.htm

Comment: ok, get `TBBUTTONINFO` via `TB_GETBUTTONINFOW` is very easy. but you *need to hide a sys-tray icon of a external app* - how you detect  your app button index ? by *pszText* in `TBBUTTONINFO` ? you know this string exactly ? if yes - no problem get index and send `TB_DELETEBUTTON`

Comment: @Christos Lytras In the commentaries above I explained why I have motivation to learn to do this programatically. Thanks for comment.

Comment: @RbMm sending a TB_GETBUTTONINFO (ansi or unicode) message to the notification area will literally break the running explorer instance, I supose the access/read to memory is related for the reasons that are clarified in the comments above by other users. Please, read the entire question and the commentaries above. I know its a lot of text written but... otherwise this kind of generic comments like "send A and get B" that are already discussed does not help me. Thanks for comment.

Comment: @ElektroStudios sending `TB_GETBUTTONINFO` is nothing break. if correct send, work ok. get `TBBUTTONINFO` with say button text easy, not problem - are this your final target ? or what

Comment: @RbMm, a quote from a comment of mine above: "please note that my ultimate goal is not to retrieve the button name. The first step is to identify the button by its (known) name, that is just to retrieve its button index, and finally send TB_DELETEBUTTON toolbar message to delete that button passing its button index."

Comment: @ElektroStudios - i can send TB_GETBUTTONINFOand got any information, including button text. nothing break or crash. but what next ? what you will do with button text ? you can detect your app by text ?

Comment: Sorry, sending TB_GETBUTTON message is what breaks the explorer instance, not TB_GETBUTTONINFO. But TB_GETBUTTONINFO just return a TBBUTTONINFO structure with empty fields (button name, button index, etc), because is not marshaled back properly when sending the message to another process. Or at least that is what I understood in @Eric Brown answer, but if you really have a working example then please publish it.

Comment: @ElektroStudios of course i have working code of get button text via `TB_GETBUTTONINFO` - this is enough for you ?

Comment: I answered you about what is my final goal in the comment above, I know the button text, I need to determine its index to be able pass that button index in TB_DELETEBUTTON toolbar message, to delete that button. So, knowing the button name, I just need its button index to be able delete the button through TB_DELETEBUTTON  message.

Comment: @ElektroStudios yes and I quoted your *alternate* on doing what are you trying to do. The creator of the system does not want you to do this, otherwise they'd permit such a case without any **hacks**. There are so many other things to learn on using Windows API. This sounds to me like *I wanna learn how to write a script that deletes the root drive "C:\", just to know how to do it* which of course involves bypassing system security mechanisms. So, good luck hacking windows.

Comment: @Christos Lytras well,you are free to think whatever you want to think, I explained that I want to learn how to do this kind of thing programatically, just because I already have implemented all the necessary win32 members and I want to give it a use in a commercial API of mine. If you really want to know, the personal usage interest that I have is to hide the icon of 'Alt-Tab Terminator' program (https://www.ntwind.com/software/alttabter.html).Anyways I don't see what relationship could have hiding a external app icon,with deleting files...but please stop accusing of similar malicious things.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - ok, look for https://stackoverflow.com/a/55631705/6401656

Comment: @ElektroStudios that was just a comparison to what you're trying to do, not an accusation. Please read carefully before you accuse me that I'm accusing you. The relation is that both cases involve bypassing system security mechanisms, and yes, like it or not that is a malicious thing to do.

Comment: Yes, you started throwing a comparison that is a synonymous of insinuation or accusation. Then, for you managing the buttons in a way like this is malicious: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10807/Shell-Tray-Info-Arrange-your-system-tray-icons . If I can see/learn the proper way in VB.NET to be able get the button index that I want to obtain, then later I could acchieve to do things like that button manager software, and I really like that idea to manage the buttons, there is nothing malicious. Thankyou anyways for comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:  The originally posted code was in error in assuming that Intptr could be coersed to work across the bitness boundary.  That mistake has been corrected.

I have also expanded the tray button data retrieval to retrieve a the button icon if possible. The Code Project article: [Shell Tray Info - Arrange your system tray icons](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10807/Shell-Tray-Info-Arrange-your-system-tray-icons) was used as the basis for writing this .Net implementation.

Do note that retrieved Icon instances do not own their respective handles as those are still owned by the OS.

---

The TBBUTTON structure is a bit of pain as fields after `fsStyle` vary their size based on the OS bitness (32/64).  The following works on my system Win 10 (64 bit) for both x86 and x64 compilations.  I apologize for the length and apparent formatting (I use 2 char tab stops and SO really messes with the formatting of multiple tabs), but I wish to present all code used in the example.

First is my TBBUTTON declaration.  It is defined as base class and a class for 32-bit and class for 64-bit OS.  The base class has a factory method (`TBBUTTON.CreateForOS`) to return the proper implementation.  I deal with the varying field sizes by declaring byte place-holders to receive the marshaled structure and re-assemble when needed.

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

```
' Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-tbbutton
' For info on native type size: Windows Data Types
'   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg/windows-data-types

'   typedef struct _TBBUTTON {
'       int       iBitmap;
'       int       idCommand;
'       Byte      fsState;
'       Byte      fsStyle;
'   #If ...
'       Byte      bReserved[6]; - 64 bit
'   #Else
'       BYTE      bReserved[2]; - 32 bit
'   #End If
'       DWORD_PTR dwData; ' DWORD_PTR = ULONG_PTR  32/64 bits OS=> 4/8 bytes
'       INT_PTR   iString; ' 32/64 bits OS => 4/8 bytes

' ref:  How to Display Tooltips for Buttons
'               https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/display-tooltips-for-buttons
'               Set the tooltip text as the iString member of the TBBUTTON structure for each button.
' so iString is a pointer to the Tooltip text

'   } TBBUTTON, *PTBBUTTON, *LPTBBUTTON;

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Friend MustInherit Class TBBUTTON

    Public iBitmap As Int32
    Public idCommand As Int32
    Public fsState As NativeMethods.ToolBars.TBSTATE
    Public fsStyle As Byte
    Protected bReserved0 As Byte
    Protected bReserved1 As Byte

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Is64Bit As Boolean
        Get
            Return Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared Function CreateForOS() As TBBUTTON
        Dim ret As TBBUTTON = Nothing
        If AppBitnessMatchesOS() Then
            If Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem Then
                ret = New TBBUTTON64
            Else
                ret = New TBBUTTON32
            End If
        Else
            Throw New Exception($"Application is {If(Environment.Is64BitProcess, 64, 32)} bits and OS is {If(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem, 64, 32)}. Bitnesses much match.")
        End If
        Return ret
    End Function

    Private Shared Function AppBitnessMatchesOS() As Boolean
        Return Environment.Is64BitProcess.Equals(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property MarshalSize As IntPtr
        Get
            Return New IntPtr(Marshal.SizeOf(Me))
        End Get
    End Property

    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property Reserved As Byte()
    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property DwData As IntPtr
    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property IString As IntPtr
End Class

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Friend NotInheritable Class TBBUTTON32 : Inherits TBBUTTON
    Private _dwData As IntPtr
    Private _iString As IntPtr

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Reserved As Byte()
        Get
            Return New Byte() {bReserved0, bReserved1}
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property DwData As IntPtr
        Get
            Return _dwData
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property IString As IntPtr
        Get
            Return _iString
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Friend NotInheritable Class TBBUTTON64 : Inherits TBBUTTON
    Protected bReserved2 As Byte
    Protected bReserved3 As Byte
    Protected bReserved4 As Byte
    Protected bReserved5 As Byte
    Private _dwData As IntPtr
    Private _iString As IntPtr

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Reserved As Byte()
        Get
            Return New Byte() {bReserved0, bReserved1, bReserved2, bReserved3, bReserved4, bReserved5}
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property DwData As IntPtr
        Get
            Return _dwData
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property IString As IntPtr
        Get
            Return _iString
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Next is my native methods class.  This class declares various function overloads to let the interop-marshaling system perform the necessary allocations/conversions.

```
Imports System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis
Imports System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Security

Friend Class NativeMethods
    Public Const WM_User As Int32 = &H400
    Public Shared Sub FreeHGlobal(ptr As IntPtr)
        If ptr <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Class ToolBars

#Region "Constants"
        ' values from CommCtrl.h
        ''' <summary>Retrieves a count of the buttons currently in the toolbar. </summary>
        Public Const TB_BUTTONCOUNT As Int32 = WM_User + 24
        Public Const TB_GETBUTTON As Int32 = WM_User + 23
        Public Const TB_DELETEBUTTON As Int32 = WM_User + 22

        Private Const TB_GETBUTTONINFOW As Int32 = WM_User + 63
        Private Const TB_SETBUTTONINFOW As Int32 = WM_User + 64
        Private Const TB_GETBUTTONINFOA As Int32 = WM_User + 65
        Private Const TB_SETBUTTONINFOA As Int32 = WM_User + 66

        ''' <summary> The cbSize and dwMask members of this structure must be filled in prior to sending this message.</summary>
        Public Const TB_GETBUTTONINFO As Int32 = TB_GETBUTTONINFOW
        ''' <summary> The cbSize and dwMask members of this structure must be filled in prior to sending this message.</summary>
        Public Const TB_SETBUTTONINFO As Int32 = TB_SETBUTTONINFOW

        Public Const TB_GETBUTTONTEXTA As Int32 = WM_User + 45
        Public Const TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW As Int32 = WM_User + 75
        Public Const TB_GETBUTTONTEXT As Int32 = TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW

        Public Const TB_GETSTRINGW As Int32 = WM_User + 91
        Public Const TB_GETSTRINGA As Int32 = WM_User + 92
        ''' <summary>This message returns the specified string from the toolbar's string pool. It does not necessarily correspond to the text string currently being displayed by a button.</summary>
        Public Const TB_GETSTRING As Int32 = TB_GETSTRINGW

        ''' <summary>wParam and lParam must be zero. returns handle to the image list, or NULL if no image list is set.</summary>
        Public Const TB_GETIMAGELIST As Int32 = WM_User + 49
        ''' <summary>Retrieves the index of the bitmap associated with a button in a toolbar. 
        ''' wParam=Command identifier of the button whose bitmap index is to be retrieved.</summary>
        Public Const TB_GETBITMAP As Int32 = WM_User + 44

        <DllImport("comctl32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
        Public Shared Function ImageList_GetIcon(himl As IntPtr, imageIndex As Int32, flags As UInt32) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <DllImport("comctl32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
        Public Shared Function ImageList_GetImageCount(himl As IntPtr) As Int32
        End Function

#End Region

        Public Enum TBSTATE As Byte
            CHECKED = &H1
            PRESSED = &H2
            ENABLED = &H4
            HIDDEN = &H8
            INDETERMINATE = &H10
            WRAP = &H20
            ELLIPSES = &H40
            MARKED = &H80
        End Enum
    End Class

    Public Class User32
#Region "Utility Methods"
        Public Shared Function GetNotificationAreaToolBarHandle() As IntPtr
            Dim hWndTray As IntPtr = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", Nothing)
            If hWndTray <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                hWndTray = FindWindowEx(hWndTray, IntPtr.Zero, "TrayNotifyWnd", Nothing)
                If hWndTray <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                    hWndTray = FindWindowEx(hWndTray, IntPtr.Zero, "SysPager", Nothing)
                    If hWndTray <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                        hWndTray = FindWindowEx(hWndTray, IntPtr.Zero, "ToolbarWindow32", Nothing)
                        Return hWndTray
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            Return IntPtr.Zero
        End Function

        Public Shared Function GetTaskBarHandle() As IntPtr
            Dim hWndTray As IntPtr = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", Nothing)
            If hWndTray <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                hWndTray = FindWindowEx(hWndTray, IntPtr.Zero, "TrayNotifyWnd", Nothing)
                If hWndTray <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                    'hWndTray = FindWindowEx(hWndTray, IntPtr.Zero, "SysPager", Nothing)
                    If hWndTray <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                        'hWndTray = FindWindowEx(hWndTray, IntPtr.Zero, "ToolbarWindow32", Nothing)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            Return hWndTray
        End Function

#End Region

        <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
        Public Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
        Public Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal hwndParent As IntPtr, ByVal hwndChildAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
        Public Shared Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, <System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out()> ByRef lpdwProcessId As Int32) As Int32
        End Function

#Region "SendMessage Overloads"

        <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint:="SendMessage")>
        Public Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Int32, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As System.Text.StringBuilder) As Int32
        End Function

        <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint:="SendMessage")>
        Public Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Int32, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
        Public Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32
        End Function

        <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
        Public Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
        End Function

#End Region

        <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
        Friend Structure ICONINFO
            ''' <summary>Specifies whether this structure defines an icon or a cursor. A value of TRUE specifies an icon; FALSE specifies a cursor.</summary>
            Public fIcon As Boolean

            ''' <summary>Specifies the x-coordinate of a cursor's hot spot. If this structure defines an icon, the hot spot is always in the center of the icon, and this member is ignored.</summary>
            Public xHotspot As Int32

            ''' <summary>Specifies the y-coordinate of the cursor's hot spot. If this structure defines an icon, the hot spot is always in the center of the icon, and this member is ignored.</summary>
            Public yHotspot As Int32 ' 

            ''' <summary>(HBITMAP) Specifies the icon bitmask bitmap. If this structure defines a black and white icon, this bitmask is formatted so that the upper half is the icon AND bitmask and the lower half is the icon XOR bitmask. Under this condition, the height should be an even multiple of two. If this structure defines a color icon, this mask only defines the AND bitmask of the icon.</summary>
            Public hbmMask As IntPtr ' 

            ''' <summary>(HBITMAP) Handle to the icon color bitmap. This member can be optional if this structure defines a black and white icon. The AND bitmask of hbmMask is applied with the SRCAND flag to the destination; subsequently, the color bitmap is applied (using XOR) to the estination by using the SRCINVERT flag.</summary>
            Public hbmColor As IntPtr
        End Structure

        <DllImport("user32.dll")>
        Shared Function GetIconInfo(ByVal hIcon As IntPtr, ByRef piconinfo As ICONINFO) As Boolean
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Class Kernel32
        <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
        <ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)>
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        Public Shared Function CloseHandle(ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
        End Function

#Region "OpenProcess"
        <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
        Public Shared Function OpenProcess(ByVal processAccess As ProcessAccessFlags, ByVal bInheritHandle As Boolean, ByVal processId As Int32) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <Flags>
        Public Enum ProcessAccessFlags As UInt32
            All = &H1F0FFF
            Terminate = &H1
            CreateThread = &H2
            VirtualMemoryOperation = &H8
            VirtualMemoryRead = &H10
            VirtualMemoryWrite = &H20
            DuplicateHandle = &H40
            CreateProcess = &H80
            SetQuota = &H100
            SetInformation = &H200
            QueryInformation = &H400
            QueryLimitedInformation = &H1000
            Synchronize = &H100000
        End Enum
#End Region

#Region "ReadProcessMemory Overloads"
        <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
        Public Shared Function ReadProcessMemory(
            ByVal hProcess As IntPtr,
            ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr,
            ByVal lpBuffer As IntPtr,
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)> ByVal iSize As IntPtr,
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)> ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As IntPtr) As Boolean
        End Function

        <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, EntryPoint:="ReadProcessMemory")>
        Public Shared Function ReadProcessMemory(
            ByVal hProcess As IntPtr,
            ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr,
            ByRef lpBuffer As Int32,
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)> ByVal iSize As IntPtr,
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)> ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As IntPtr) As Boolean
        End Function

        <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, EntryPoint:="ReadProcessMemory")>
        Public Shared Function ReadProcessMemory(
            ByVal hProcess As IntPtr,
            ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr,
            ByRef lpBuffer As Int64,
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)> ByVal iSize As IntPtr,
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)> ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As IntPtr) As Boolean
        End Function

        <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, EntryPoint:="ReadProcessMemory")>
        Public Shared Function ReadProcessMemory(
            ByVal hProcess As IntPtr,
            ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr,
            ByVal lpBuffer As TBBUTTON,
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)> ByVal iSize As IntPtr,
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)> ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As IntPtr) As Boolean
        End Function

        <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, EntryPoint:="ReadProcessMemory")>
        Public Shared Function ReadProcessMemory(
            ByVal hProcess As IntPtr,
            ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr,
            ByVal lpBuffer As TrayData,
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)> ByVal iSize As IntPtr,
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)> ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As IntPtr) As Boolean
        End Function

#End Region

#Region "VirtualAllocEx"
        <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True)>
        Shared Function VirtualAllocEx(ByVal hProcess As IntPtr,
                                                                     ByVal lpAddress As IntPtr,
                                                                     <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)> ByVal dwSize As IntPtr,
                                                                     <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> ByVal flAllocationType As AllocationType,
                                                                     ByVal flProtect As MemoryProtection) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <Flags>
        Public Enum AllocationType As UInt32
            Commit = &H1000
            Reserve = &H2000
            Decommit = &H4000
            Release = &H8000
            Reset = &H80000
            Physical = &H400000
            TopDown = &H100000
            WriteWatch = &H200000
            LargePages = &H20000000
        End Enum

        <Flags>
        Public Enum MemoryProtection As UInt32
            Execute = &H10
            ExecuteRead = &H20
            ExecuteReadWrite = &H40
            ExecuteWriteCopy = &H80
            NoAccess = &H1
            [ReadOnly] = &H2
            ReadWrite = &H4
            WriteCopy = &H8
            GuardModifierflag = &H100
            NoCacheModifierflag = &H200
            WriteCombineModifierflag = &H400
        End Enum

#End Region

#Region "VirtualFreeEx"
        <DllImport("kernel32.dll")>
        Public Shared Function VirtualFreeEx(ByVal hProcess As IntPtr,
                                                ByVal lpAddress As IntPtr,
                                                <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)> ByVal dwSize As IntPtr,
                                                ByVal dwFreeType As FreeType) As Boolean
        End Function

        ''' <summary>helper method to release memory allocated with VirtualAllocEx</summary>
        ''' <param name="lpAddress">ptr received from VirtualAllocEx</param>
        ''' <param name="hProcess">ptr to process received from OpenProcess</param>
        Public Shared Sub ReleaseVirtualAlloc(ByRef lpAddress As IntPtr, hProcess As IntPtr)
            If lpAddress <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, lpAddress, Nothing, FreeType.RELEASE)
                lpAddress = IntPtr.Zero
            End If
        End Sub

        <Flags()>
        Public Enum FreeType As UInt32
            DECOMMIT = &H4000
            RELEASE = &H8000
        End Enum
#End Region
    End Class
End Class
```

There are two additional support classes defined below.

```
Friend Class TrayButtonInfo
    Public Property Icon As Icon
    Public Property Index As Int32
    Public Property CommandID As Int32
    Public Property DisplayText As String = String.Empty
    Public Property ProcessFound As Boolean = False
    Public Property ProcessName As String = String.Empty
    Public Property ProcessID As Int32
    Public Property State As NativeMethods.ToolBars.TBSTATE
End Class
```

...

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Friend Class TrayData
    Public hWnd As IntPtr
    Public uID As Int32
    Public uCallbackMessage As UInt32
    Public Reservered0 As UInt32
    Public Reservered1 As UInt32
    Public hIcon As IntPtr

    Public ReadOnly Property OwningProcess As Process
        Get
            Dim ret As Process = Nothing
            If hWnd <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                Dim processIDOfButton As Int32
                Dim threadId As Int32 = NativeMethods.User32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, processIDOfButton)
                Try ' Process.GetProcessById can throw an exception if the id is not found
                    ret = Process.GetProcessById(processIDOfButton)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ' eat it
                End Try
            End If
            Return ret
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Now for the actual example code.  This code prepare a list of `TrayButtonInfo` instances that can be searched to find a matching button.  It also shows an example of this search and how to delete the button.  I tried to explain the code in the comments, but feel free to ask about anything that is not clear.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim retrievedNotificationButtons As List(Of TrayButtonInfo) = PrepareButtonInfoList()

        ' Now we have filled retrievedNotificationButtons with the information for all the buttons
        ' "Realtek HD Audio Manager" is just for testing on my machine.
        ' apply criteria for finding the button you want to delete
        ' note that the button can be restored by restarting Explorer
        Dim targetBtn As TrayButtonInfo = retrievedNotificationButtons.FirstOrDefault(Function(info) info.DisplayText.StartsWith("Realtek HD Audio Manager"))
        If targetBtn IsNot Nothing Then ' delete the button
            ' the following statement will delete the button if uncommented
            'Dim toolBarHwnd As IntPtr = NativeMethods.User32.GetNotificationAreaToolBarHandle()
            'NativeMethods.User32.SendMessage(toolBarHwnd, NativeMethods.ToolBars.TB_DELETEBUTTON, targetBtn.Index, 0)
        End If
        DataGridView1.DataSource = retrievedNotificationButtons
    End Sub

    Private Function PrepareButtonInfoList() As List(Of TrayButtonInfo)
        Dim ret As List(Of TrayButtonInfo)

        ' create a TBButon structure appropriate for the OS bitness
        Dim btn As TBBUTTON = TBBUTTON.CreateForOS

        Dim toolBarProcessHandle As IntPtr
        Dim toolBarButtonProcessMemoryPtr As IntPtr

        ' obtain window handle of the notification area toolbar
        Dim toolBarHwnd As IntPtr = NativeMethods.User32.GetNotificationAreaToolBarHandle()

        ' obtain id of process that owns the notification area toolbar, threadId is of no consequence
        Dim proccessIDOwningToolBar As Int32
        Dim threadId As Int32 = NativeMethods.User32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(toolBarHwnd, proccessIDOwningToolBar)

        Try
            ' obtain handle to the toolbar process that will allow allocating,reading and writing
            toolBarProcessHandle = NativeMethods.Kernel32.OpenProcess(NativeMethods.Kernel32.ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryOperation Or
                                                                                                    NativeMethods.Kernel32.ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryRead Or
                                                                                                    NativeMethods.Kernel32.ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryWrite,
                                                                                                    False, proccessIDOwningToolBar)

            ' allocate memory in the toolbar process to hold the TBButton
            ' need ReadWrite access due to TB_GETBUTTON writing to the allocated memory
            toolBarButtonProcessMemoryPtr = NativeMethods.Kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(toolBarProcessHandle,
                                                                                                                            Nothing,
                                                                                                                            btn.MarshalSize,
                                                                                                                            NativeMethods.Kernel32.AllocationType.Commit,
                                                                                                                            NativeMethods.Kernel32.MemoryProtection.ReadWrite)

            ' now we can request the toolbar to fill the allocated memory with a TBButton structure
            ' for each button in the notifiaction area.

            ' determine how many toolbar buttons are visible notification area contains
            Dim buttonCount As Int32 = NativeMethods.User32.SendMessage(toolBarHwnd, NativeMethods.ToolBars.TB_BUTTONCOUNT, 0, 0)
            ret = New List(Of TrayButtonInfo)(buttonCount)

            For btnIndex As Int32 = 0 To buttonCount - 1

                Dim btnInfo As New TrayButtonInfo With {.Index = btnIndex}
                ret.Add(btnInfo)

                If NativeMethods.User32.SendMessage(toolBarHwnd, NativeMethods.ToolBars.TB_GETBUTTON, btnIndex, toolBarButtonProcessMemoryPtr) Then
                    ' the toolbar owning process has successfully filled toolBarButtonProcessMemoryPtr

                    ' use a customize ReadProcessMemory that takes a TBButtonBase instance as the destination buffer
                    If NativeMethods.Kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(toolBarProcessHandle, toolBarButtonProcessMemoryPtr, btn, btn.MarshalSize, Nothing) Then
                        ' btn has been loaded, get the data

                        btnInfo.CommandID = btn.idCommand
                        btnInfo.State = btn.fsState

                        ' Note that per the documentation, TBBUTTON.iString can contain a pointer the Tooltip Text
                        ' In testing it does, but I have not found out how to determine the length of the string
                        ' without the length, a guess on the size of process memory to read must be made and that
                        ' seems unwise when accessing memory.
                        ' GetButtonText use the TB_GETBUTTONTEXT message.  This message's documentation indicates
                        ' that the retrieved text may differ from the Tooltip text.  As Tooltip text can be provided
                        ' via several mechanisms, this makes sense.
                        btnInfo.DisplayText = GetButtonText(btnInfo.CommandID, toolBarHwnd, toolBarProcessHandle)

                        ' get the process pointed to by dwData
                        ' according to: Code Project article: A tool to order the window buttons in your taskbar
                        ' https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10497/A-tool-to-order-the-window-buttons-in-your-taskbar
                        ' this is a pointer to the window handle of the process that owns the button
                        ' while I can find no documentation that this is true, it appears to work

                        GetButtonData(btn, toolBarProcessHandle, btnInfo)

                    End If ' ReadProcessMemoryToTBButton
                End If
            Next

        Finally ' cleanup handles
            If toolBarProcessHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                NativeMethods.Kernel32.ReleaseVirtualAlloc(toolBarButtonProcessMemoryPtr, toolBarProcessHandle)
            End If
            If toolBarProcessHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                NativeMethods.Kernel32.CloseHandle(toolBarProcessHandle)
                toolBarProcessHandle = IntPtr.Zero
            End If
        End Try

        Return ret
    End Function

    Private Function GetButtonText(CommandID As Int32, toolBarWindowHandle As IntPtr, toolBarProcessHandle As IntPtr) As String
        Dim ret As String = String.Empty
        '1st determine the number of characters to retrieve
        Dim lenText As Int32 = NativeMethods.User32.SendMessage(toolBarWindowHandle, NativeMethods.ToolBars.TB_GETBUTTONTEXT, New IntPtr(CommandID), IntPtr.Zero).ToInt32
        If lenText > 0 Then
            Dim ptrToText As IntPtr
            Dim localBuffer As IntPtr
            Try
                Dim numBytes As New IntPtr((lenText * 2) + 1) ' Unicode 2 bytes per character + 1 for null terminator
                'need to allocate the string in the process space
                ptrToText = NativeMethods.Kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(toolBarProcessHandle,
                                                                                        Nothing,
                                                                                        numBytes,
                                                                                        NativeMethods.Kernel32.AllocationType.Commit,
                                                                                        NativeMethods.Kernel32.MemoryProtection.ReadWrite)

                Dim receivedLen As Int32 = NativeMethods.User32.SendMessage(toolBarWindowHandle, NativeMethods.ToolBars.TB_GETBUTTONTEXT, New IntPtr(CommandID), ptrToText).ToInt32
                localBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(numBytes) ' allocate local buffer to receive bytes from process space
                If NativeMethods.Kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(toolBarProcessHandle, ptrToText, localBuffer, numBytes, Nothing) Then
                    ret = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(localBuffer)
                End If

            Finally ' release handles to unmanaged memory
                NativeMethods.Kernel32.ReleaseVirtualAlloc(ptrToText, toolBarProcessHandle)
                NativeMethods.FreeHGlobal(localBuffer)
            End Try
        End If
        Return ret
    End Function

    Private Sub GetButtonData(btn As TBBUTTON, toolBarProcessHandle As IntPtr, btnInfo As TrayButtonInfo)

        Dim data As TrayData
        Try
            data = New TrayData()
            Dim dataMarshalSize As New IntPtr(Marshal.SizeOf(data))
            If NativeMethods.Kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(toolBarProcessHandle, btn.DwData, data, dataMarshalSize, Nothing) Then

                ' use GetIconInfo to validate icon handle
                Dim iconInfo As New NativeMethods.User32.ICONINFO
                If NativeMethods.User32.GetIconInfo(data.hIcon, iconInfo) Then
                    btnInfo.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(data.hIcon)
                End If

                Using p As Process = data.OwningProcess
                    If p IsNot Nothing Then
                        btnInfo.ProcessFound = True
                        btnInfo.ProcessID = p.Id
                        btnInfo.ProcessName = p.ProcessName
                    End If
                End Using
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

One thing that I observed in limited testing is that intermitantly, addition characters are post-pended onto the retrieved button text.  I tried zeroing the memory but that did not help.  Hence the use of the `StartsWith` when searching for a target button to delete.

Answer (score 1):

we can send [`TB_GETBUTTONINFOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tb-getbuttoninfo) for get the button text. if we know what text must be for button - we can detect it by text and delete it via `TB_DELETEBUTTON`. the pointer to [`TBBUTTONINFOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-tbbuttoninfow) of course must be valid in context of process, which own the hwnd. the *pszText* inside [`TBBUTTONINFOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-tbbuttoninfow) also of course must be valid in context of target process.

for implement this - the best create section and map it in self and target process. this let easy manipulate with memory.

```
BOOL IsTargetButton(PCWSTR pszText);

HWND GetNotificationWnd()
{
    HWND hwnd;

    (hwnd = FindWindow(L"Shell_TrayWnd", 0)) && 
        (hwnd = FindWindowExW(hwnd, 0, L"TrayNotifyWnd", 0)) &&
        (hwnd = FindWindowExW(hwnd, 0, L"SysPager", 0)) &&
        (hwnd = FindWindowExW(hwnd, 0, L"ToolbarWindow32", 0));

    return hwnd;
}

void deleteInTray()
{
    if (HWND hwnd = GetNotificationWnd())
    {
        if (ULONG iIndex = SendMessageW(hwnd, TB_BUTTONCOUNT, 0, 0))
        {
            ULONG dwProcessId;
            if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwProcessId))
            {
                if (HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, FALSE, dwProcessId))
                {
                    HANDLE hSection;

                    LARGE_INTEGER Size = { 1 };
                    if (0 <= ZwCreateSection(&hSection, SECTION_ALL_ACCESS, 0, &Size, PAGE_READWRITE, SEC_COMMIT, 0))
                    {
                        SIZE_T ViewSize = 0;

                        union {
                            PVOID RemoteBaseAddress;
                            PBYTE pb2;
                        };

                        union {
                            PVOID BaseAddress;
                            TBBUTTONINFO* ptbi;
                            PBYTE pb;
                        };

                        if (0 <= ZwMapViewOfSection(hSection, NtCurrentProcess(), &(BaseAddress = 0), 
                            0, 0, 0, &ViewSize, ViewUnmap, 0, PAGE_READWRITE))
                        {
                            if (0 <= ZwMapViewOfSection(hSection, hProcess, &(RemoteBaseAddress = 0), 
                                0, 0, 0, &ViewSize, ViewUnmap, 0, PAGE_READWRITE))
                            {
                                ptbi->cbSize = sizeof(TBBUTTONINFO);
                                ptbi->dwMask = TBIF_BYINDEX|TBIF_TEXT;
                                ptbi->pszText = (PWSTR)(pb2 + sizeof(TBBUTTONINFO));
                                ptbi->cchText = ((int)ViewSize - sizeof(TBBUTTONINFO)) / sizeof(WCHAR);

                                PWSTR pszText = (PWSTR)(pb + sizeof(TBBUTTONINFO));

                                do 
                                {
                                    if (0 <= SendMessageW(hwnd, TB_GETBUTTONINFOW, --iIndex, (LPARAM)RemoteBaseAddress))
                                    {
                                        DbgPrint("%u: %S\n", iIndex, pszText);

                                        if (IsTargetButton(pszText))
                                        {
                                            SendMessageW(hwnd, TB_DELETEBUTTON, iIndex, 0);
                                        }
                                    }
                                } while (iIndex);

                                ZwUnmapViewOfSection(hProcess, RemoteBaseAddress);
                            }

                            ZwUnmapViewOfSection(NtCurrentProcess(), BaseAddress);
                        }
                        CloseHandle(hSection);
                    }

                    CloseHandle(hProcess);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help and time writting this, however I asked precisely for a solution written in VB.NET. I don't manage C/C++. In fact, I linked another possible C++ solution in the question update of 25-March-2019, but when attempting to translate it to VB.NET I have many difficulties (that I mentioned in the question update). A solution written in C# would be totally acceptable from my side, but only in case of it does not use methodologies that are not reproducible in VB.NET.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - i dont know VB.NET, however my solution also not 100% equal, i not use Read/write process memory. shared section instead

Comment: That is an interesting information. I suppose that using the undocumented functions '**Nt*...**' (like **NtMapViewOfSection**) are equivalent functions that could be able to reproduce the same as your calls to "Zw*..." functions?. Anyways I'm lost in the translation to C# or VB.NET with the usage of **union** keyword inside a method block from your code, and some other things.

Comment: @ElektroStudios the [`NtMapViewOfSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwmapviewofsection) is well documented function. `union` i use for make code more short and simply from *c++*, however this is very optional and not mandatory here

Comment: I really like this solution and I would like to try implement it in VB.NET, however as I'm saying I don't know the basics of C/C++ so probably at the end I can't translate this code properly, but I will try it in the next days. Thanks again.

Comment: While I was trying to implement the required P/Invokes, I noticed that you use both NtClose and CloseHandle functions. Can I ask why you use NtClose?. The MSDN says it is deprecated and suggest to use CloseHandle instead. It is really necessary to use NtClose?, it makes any difference in your code?.

Comment: Also I'm not understanding why for some things you use the Zw* functions instead of the Nt* functions, for example NtCreateSection instead of ZwCreateSection, and ZwMapViewOfSection instead of NtMapViewOfSection. I imagine that any Zw* and Nt* will point to the same entry point function, however it is a little bit confussing that you are using both Zw* and Nt* functions in your code. Please correct me if I'm wrong about something.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - the `CloseHandle` thin shell over `NtClose` can use `CloseHandle` only - no difference here. in user mode no difference between *Zw* and *Nt* - thay really point to the same function. can use any

Comment: What exact numeric value is for '**PAGE_SIZE**' constant?. I'm having difficulties to find it in the Windows SDK and Google...

Comment: @ElektroStudios - this is 0x4000. but you need understand that this is arbitrary value. here can use any "big enough"

Comment: maybe could you read the **UPDATE (13-APRIL-2019)** section that I added to the main post?. There you will find my attempt to translate your code to VB.NET / C#. I don't know if you manage .NET, but maybe with a single look to the code you could notice what mistakes I'm doing.... thanks.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - sorry, i dont understand any managed languages.

Comment: ok, thank you anyways, but then if you can let me ask you one doubt I have that maybe can clarify me some things: in your code, the call to **SendMessage** is used to 'store' a **TBBUTTONINFOW** struct in **RemoteBaseAddress** (which is just an 'empty' space of specific size), so when the call to **SendMessage** returns, **RemoteBaseAddress**  stores a **TBBUTTONINFOW** struct and **RemoteBaseAddress** has the exact size of a **TBBUTTONINFOW** struct. I'm right with these assumptions?.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - i create section (via `NtCreateSection`) and map this section (via `ZwMapViewOfSection`) in both self and remote process. the `BaseAddress` point to section memory in my process and `RemoteBaseAddress` point to section memory in explorer. but memory is the **same** (because bassed on the same section). i pass `RemoteBaseAddress` to remothe process (and init `ptbi->pszText` with it, because this will be used in explorer). in self process i access memory via `BaseAddress`. the `union` this is only reinterpritation of value, for easy access

Comment: @ElektroStudios - also look your code, despite i not understand, serrious doubt in some moments, say how you use `viewSize` in call `NativeMethods.NtMapViewOfSection` maybe correct `ref ViewSize`, for example https://github.com/hfiref0x/UACME/blob/master/Source/Fujinami/EntryPoint.cs#L110

Comment: At the end, applying the concept of using a section object in .NET following your steps I was able to retrieve a working TBBUTTON struct, however I cannot say the same for TBBUTTONINFO (ANSI or UNICODE) struct on which for some reason all the fields returned on this struct were zero/null. I don't know why this happens, but it is very frustrating to me. I tested different TBBUTTONINFO definitions and I'm sure that is not the problem after I ensured the offset of the native C/C++ struct corresponds to the .NET definition. Something very strange to me. I just wanted to comment you this.

Comment: @ElektroStudios if  for `TBBUTTONINFO` all the fields returned on this struct were zero/null this mean that some error in your code. and use only UNICODE always

Answer (score 0):

You can't send the `TB_GETBUTTON` message to windows in another process and get valid results, because `TB_GETBUTTON` needs to manipulate a pointer to a struct, and window messages that do that have to marshal the struct.  Very few windows messages do that.  `TB_GETBUTTONCOUNT` works because it doesn't need to be marshaled.

Comment: `TB_GETBUTTON` **can** be sent to another process. You just have to give it the address of a `TBBUTTON` that exists in the target process's address space. Use `VirtualAllocEx()` to allocate it, then send the message, then use `ReadProcessMemory()` to read its content.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thanks for comment, please could you illustrate us with a code example of **VirtualAllocEx()** usage for a struct or for this concrete example with **TBBUTTON**?